# Youtube video does not play in webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-youtube-api

I have tried so much but youtube video is not loading in webview instead **if i click on video the share and like action bar will be displayed**

below is my source code

```
     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(sabNZBurl);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

}

```
     class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    // Show in WebView instead of Browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        WebView engine = new WebView(YoutubeActivity.this);
        engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        Log.i("YoutubeActivity", "MyWebViewClient: shouldOverrideUrlLoading");

        String temp = "<object " + "width='220' height='200'" + ">" + "<param name='allowFullScreen' value='false'>" + "</param><param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>" + "</param><embed src='"
                + url + "'" + " type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true'" + "width='220' height='200'" + "></embed></object>";

        engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        engine.loadData(temp, "text/html", "utf-8");
        return true;
    }
```

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
       <activity
        android:name=".Youtube.YoutubeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

the screen shot is below

[image]

[image]

when i click on youtube video the actionbar will come with like and share button but video does not load

Comment: what is version of your android OS, What URL you are using, is it youtube url for mobile, i.e starting with RTSP. In addition i once i was trying to play youtube for in android VideoView, it never plays due to video format supporting issue, i used this https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/source/browse/trunk/OpenYouTubeActivity/src/com/keyes/youtube/YouTubeUtility.java It calculates Youtube's mp4 url which android can play, i dont know if it still work or not because youtube was blocked mp4 url calculation.

Comment: andorid 2.3.... but about URL it can be any url

Comment: please read my comment again i have updated it,, as your os is 2.3, there are video format supporting issues

Comment: thanks you so much for your nice reply but i want to play in webview...

Comment: once you are successfully able to convert its url you can play it in webview... weather it is RTSP or else if is playable

Comment: RTSP videos are of low quality and they 're for mobile compatible.

Comment: ya all video are RTSP video